# Select list items with a certain class but only if they are the last in the group

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Let's say there is a list that looks like this:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li> 
<ul>
```

I'm trying to find a way to select all the list items with the class `unique`, but only if this item is the last one in the group, meaning that all list items with the class `unique` that come before this item should not be selected.

Is there any way to achieve the desired behavior if the HTML structure cannot be changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `:has` can be used (not currently supported by Firefox), it could be:

```
.unique:has(+ :not(.unique)) {
  color: crimson;
}
```

[More about `:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Example: (not compatible with Firefox, IE, and older browsers)

```css
@supports (selector(html:has(body))) {
  .unique:has(+ :not(.unique)) {
    color: crimson;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li> 
<ul>
```

If `:has` is not an option, perhaps use some Javascript code for this as a fallback solution.

Example: (fallback solution with Javascript)

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll("li");

items.forEach((item, index, arr) => {
  if (!item.classList.contains("unique")) return;
  if (index < arr.length - 1 && arr[index + 1].classList.contains("unique"))
    return;
  item.classList.add("last");
});
```

```css
.last {
  color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
  <li class="item unique">Text</li> // <-- Should be selected
  <li class="item">Text</li>
<ul>
```